# Make entire EditText viewable?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Here is my problem:
[image: The problem]
The keyboard covers up the EditText. How can I prevent this from happening? Here is my original view (without the keyboard):
[image: Original]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put your entire view within the tab into a scrollview which will allow the users of your app to scroll the activity up to see the edit box.